# Is there some documents for mdf, ndf, ldf file format?

Tags: sql-server, file-format, mdf, ldf

Is there some documents for mdf, ndf, ldf file format?

Here the three different file types are belonged to SQL server.

I search the document on internet for a long time, but the result is disappointed. Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - and you're not supposed to fiddle around with bits and bytes in those files anyway! Use the proper API's (T-SQL)

Comment: @snakecon
: perhaps you should tell us what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I want to recover my invalid file in bits and bytes level. So I wander if there is proper documents like Word and Excel.

Comment: @snakecon: no, there is no safe way to read a data file *at all*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is information on the structures of SQL Server files, however, it's by no means as straightforward as a Word or Excel document.

You can look [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/gg313760.aspx) for information on .MDF and .NDF (database files), and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/gg313762.aspx) for .LDF files (Log files).

This is MCM (Microsoft Master) level training, and that alone should give you an idea of the level of complexity involved. If you have a corrupt SQL Server database, you should look at restoring a backup, depending on how recent it was.